What is missing from this proof in topology?
I am reading the Wikipedia entry Proper Map, particularly the "Partial proof of equivalence", copied as follows.

Let $f : X \to Y$ be a closed map, such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is compact (in $X$) for all $y \in Y.$ Let $K$ be a compact subset of $Y.$ It remains to show that $f^{-1}(K)$ is compact.
Let $\left\{U_a : a \in A\right\}$ be an open cover of $f^{-1}(K).$ Then for all $k \in K$ this is also an open cover of $f^{-1}(k).$ Since the latter is assumed to be compact, it has a finite subcover. In other words, for every $k \in K,$ there exists a finite subset $\gamma_k \subseteq A$ such that $f^{-1}(k) \subseteq \cup_{a \in \gamma_k} U_{a}.$
The set $X \setminus \cup_{a \in \gamma_k} U_{a}$ is closed in $X$ and its image under $f$ is closed in $Y$ because $f$ is a closed map. Hence the set
$$
V_k = Y \setminus f\left(X \setminus \cup_{a \in \gamma_k} U_{a}\right)
$$
is open in $Y.$ It follows that $V_k$ contains the point $k.$
Now $K \subseteq \cup_{k \in K} V_k$ and because $K$ is assumed to be compact, there are finitely many points $k_1, \dots, k_s$ such that $K \subseteq \cup_{i =1}^s V_{k_i}.$ Furthermore, the set $\Gamma = \cup_{i=1}^s \gamma_{k_i}$ is a finite union of finite sets, which makes $\Gamma$ a finite set.
Now it follows that $f^{-1}(K) \subseteq f^{-1}\left( \cup_{i=1}^s V_{k_i} \right) \subseteq \cup_{a \in \Gamma} U_{a}$ and we have found a finite subcover of $f^{-1}(K),$ which completes the proof.

I am unsure about the last line. The
Let $S:=\bigcup_{a\in\gamma_k}U_a $. I have
\begin{align}
f(X\setminus S)&\supseteq f(X)\setminus f(S) \\
\implies Y\setminus f(X\setminus S)&\subseteq Y\setminus (f(X)\setminus f(S))=(Y\setminus f(X))\cup f(S) \\
\implies f^{-1}(Y\setminus f(X\setminus S))&\subseteq f^{-1}(f(S))
\end{align}
However, $f^{-1}(f(S))\supseteq S$. I do not see how the equality can be achieved. The non-equality prevents me from reaching the conclusion in the last line of the proof on that Wikipedia page
$$f^{-1}\left( \cup_{i=1}^s V_{k_i} \right) \subseteq \cup_{a \in \Gamma} U_{a}.$$
What is missing?

$f^{-1}\left( \cup_{i=1}^s V_{k_i} \right) \subseteq\cup_{i=1}^s
 f^{-1}\left(  V_{k_i} \right)$.
Now, for a fixed $k$, let $S:=\bigcup_{a\in\gamma_k}U_a$.
For every $x\in  f^{-1}\left(  V_k\right)$, we have $f(x)\notin f(X\setminus S)$ (by definition of $V_k$), hence $x\notin X\setminus S$, i.e. $x\in S$.
A fortiori, $x\in 
\bigcup_{a\in\Gamma}U_a$.
More briefly:
$$\begin{align}f^{-1}(Y\setminus f(X\setminus S))&=X\setminus f^{-1}(f(X\setminus S))\\&\subseteq X\setminus (X\setminus S)\\&=S.\end{align}$$

Oh, darn. It is so obvious. I bounded $f$ first then $f^{-1}$. I should have tried next the other way around, i.e., bounding $f^{-1}$ first then $f$. I am so embarrassed to have posted this question...
